# How to read json in Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activesupport

So, I'm doing like that at my controller action:

```
json_document = JSON(params) (json gem)
```

If I print json_document it gives me a Json like that:

```
 {"createdAt":"Mar 6, 2012 6:12:54 PM","id":177139718620856322,"text":"@rgjunio where?","source":"web","isTruncated":false,"inReplyToStatusId":177139644012572673, ...
```

But when I try to access it:

```
tweet = Complaint.find_by_twitter_status json_document["inReplyToStatusId"]
```

i get the following error:

```
can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String
```

So i tried another way using symbols:

```
tweet = Complaint.find_by_twitter_status json_document[:inReplyToStatusId]
```

but it gives me the error:

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into Integer)
```

Any idea?

Update:
If I use  params[:inReplyToStatusId] isntead I got the following:

```
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SELECT  "complaints".* FROM "complaints"  WHERE "complaints"."twitter_status" = 177144980450721794 LIMIT 1):
```

Comment: You need to change your `twitter_status` column to type `bigint` to accept the params input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
params[:inReplyToStatusId].to_s
```

Comment: That's it. It was a String field, the error message made me think it was a big int. Thanks.